# Monaco Editor SignatureHelpProvider Implementation

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I have been digging around for quite some time now trying to find a working example to implement a `SignatureHelpProvider` in typescript for a custom programming language used internally within my company.

In my time so far I have a minimally working example that provides "Parameter Hints" (another name for what the SignatureHelpProvider result is) for methods like:

`ADD(1, 2)` - things work somewhat well for basic 1 level deep methods.

[image]

However, things are getting very complex and difficult to manage for things like:

`ADD(1, ADD(1, SUBTRACT(100, 5)))` etc

In doing some research, someone suggested that building an AST is the right approach for managing this type of project. However, I have not been able to find any complete examples online  for implementing `SignatureHelpProvider` with a custom programming language.

**Does anyone know of a good resource / example to use for implementing** `SignatureHelpProvider` **in a custom programming language?**

Have reviewed the online docs extensively, and poured over VS Code's internal  implementation, no dice so far. (https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/languageFeatures.ts#L369 & https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.signaturehelpprovider.html#providesignaturehelp)

Comment: think your question might be more about parsing your custom language than using the the `SignatureHelpProvider` - the latter is pretty simple to use